# Given $(X,Y) \sim N_2(\mu, \sigma^2)$, is the following logic correct? If not, why?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

X and Y are independently distributed if they are elements of a random vector with bivariate normal distribution, true or false?

If they are independently distributed, then $P(c_1 < Y < c_2 | X=x) = P(Y < c_2|X=x) - P(Y < c_2 | X=x)$.

And in general $P(Y<y|X=x) = \frac{P[(X=x)\cap(Y<y)]}{P(X=x)}$

but because of independence, $P(X=x \cap Y<y)=P(X=x)P(X<y)$

So in the end we just need $P(c_1<Y<c_2)$...

I have the strong sense that I am missing the mark here.

Comment: Note $P(X=x)$ is $0$, so you may not divide by it.  But your conclusion is correct nonetheless.

Comment: The question was very well answered by @gt6989b. My question was twofold: 1.) Are the elements of a random vector with bivariate, normal distribution always independent. His answer was "no". My second question was whether or not the flow of my logic, given that those variables were indeed independent was correct. And his answer was "yes". I flagged Did's comment as unnecessary, and I wish there was an extra flag for "snobby". This community could use a "snob" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, in general, if $X,Y$ are independent and $E_Y$ and $E_X$ are any events dependent only on $Y$ and $X$ respectively, then
$$
\mathbb{P}\left[\left.E_Y \right| E_X\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[E_Y\right],
$$
which gives rise to the name of this relationship, which we call *independence*, meaning that $Y$-events are in some sense independent of $X$-events, and this clarifies in which sense exactly.

Comment: What about the fact that (X,Y) is a bivariate normal distribution? Does that mean that X and Y are necessarily independent?

Comment: @rocksNwaves No, any relationship can be captured in a bivariate distribution. However, if the bivariate distribution is the product of univariate distribution functions, the random variables are independent

Comment: One more clarification. Since normal distribution describes a continuous random variable, and the question asks the $P(Y<y|X=x)$ how is the whole thing not zero because we have involved the probability of X at a discrete point, $P(X=x) = 0$?

Comment: I have no idea how to compute that limit, either. That makes the whole thing more confusing now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @rocksNwaves this is a good question. the author is using a *terrible* abuse of notation, in this cases using the discrete analogy, where the pdf is $f_Z(z) = \mathbb{P}[Z=z]$ and is well-defined that way. Instead of $\mathbb{P}[X = x]$, in the continuous case he ought to write $$\lim_{h \to 0} \mathbb{P}[X \in (x-h, x+h)] = f_X(x)$$ (i.e. it is just the pdf of $X$) but he was really lazy and used the discrete short-hand.

Comment: @rocksNwaves I changed the comment to make it more explicit, the limit is just the continuous pdf directly, which is why a discrete pdf shorthand was used

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\mathbb{P}(Y|X) = \mathbb{P}(Y)$. So in your case,

$\begin{array}{lcl}
\mathbb{P}(c_1<Y<c_2| X=x) &=& \mathbb{P}(c_1<Y<c_2) \\
 & = &  \mathbb{P}(Y<c_2) -\mathbb{P}(Y<c_1) \\
& = & \mathbb{P}(Y<c_2| X=x) -\mathbb{P}(Y<c_1| X=x)
\end{array}$

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: What about the fact that (X,Y) is a bivariate normal distribution? Does that mean that X and Y are necessarily independent?

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is a gaussian vector, then they are indeed indepentent. But if not, the fact that they are a bivariate normal distribution only gives you the fact that

$Cov(X,Y) = 0 \implies P(X\cap Y) = P(X)P(Y)$

http://bit.ly/2yZTAeF